# Unable to find any AttachmentDelete/Removed event on Outlook MailItem

Tags: c#, outlook, attachment, mailitem

I am doing some stuff whenever an attachment is added to a being-composed mailItem, on AttachmentAdd event of MailItem, and things work fine. Now I want to undo the same stuff, when an attachment is removed, and I dont see any AttachmentDelete/Removed event or anything similar.

Is there a way to get a notification/event when an attachment is removed from a being-composed mailItem?

Any pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently OutlookInterop v11 does not have AttachmentRemove event, but v12 does. So updating the reference did the job.